# TeamCity database is empty or doesn't exist. message. The database does exist

Tags: teamcity

After server ran out of disk space because TeamCity created a huge > 5GB file in the CH subfolder of system/message folder I deleted the whole CH subfolder to free the disk space

After I restarted the TC service, I got the following message on the web page.

> TeamCity database is empty or doesn't exist. If you proceed, a new
>   empty database will be created.

All of the files in the  folder, except deleted CH folder are intact.

Is there a way to make the TeamCity work without losing the current database?